# How to add searchbox in applicationBar windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have to implement a search functionality on my current page for that I want to add a `searchbox` in `ApplicationBar` .

Please tell me how to add `Textbox` in `Applcationbar`.

Comment: is your application, for `Windows Phone 8` or `Windows Phone 8.1`..? coz you've tagged both platforms in your question.

Comment: You really should provide us more information: some example code, what you've tried, the exact platform (as @KevalLangalia mentioned). Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Phone ApplicationBar shows only buttons. You cannot place arbitrary controls such as TextBoxes in it. If you want the effect of a TextBox in a bar at the bottom of the screen you can position a panel (StackPanel, Grid, etc.) at the bottom of the screen with your Text Box in it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a text box in application bar, but you can enable a textbox when the search key is pressed using an event handler and probably you can also disable that text box when your done.

you can use textbox.visibility or textbox.isEnabled properties.